# How do I validate URL, but ignore if http:// or blank?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-routing

I want to validate a form field for URL. I have set the default for the field to http://. When the user doesn't enter a URL, and leaves the http://, it says invalid URL. URL is not required, so if it's only http://, it should not show error message. How can I make it ignore if the person submits http:// as the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*http://* is not a valid url, so if you want to allow it anyway there are 2 options

1. create a [custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules), that returns true for a real url + *http://*
2. use the [before validate callback](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1051/beforeValidate) and set the url field to blank if it is just *http://*

hope that helps

**EDIT**

I forgot: you don't need to set required but `'allowEmpty' => true`

[required](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1147/required) -> the form must contain a field xyz that is send to the server

[allowEmpty](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1148/allowEmpty)-> a field may be blank

---

I added the link to the callback function above, but anyway .. here it is:

in your model class (I just suppose it's `User`):

```
class User extends AppModel {
    ..

    function beforeValidate() {
        if (isset($this->data['User']['url']) && $this->data['User']['url'] == 'http://') {
            $this->data['User']['url'] = '';
        }
        return true;
    }
    ..
}
```

---

Comment: How do I use beforeValidate()? I can't find any examples. Is it a function? How do I pull the submitted variables up: $data['SubmitedForm']['URL']? Thanks

Comment: try to use $this->data[$this->alias][...] because the name of the class can change...